# React/redux benefit with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

We develop a Ruby on Rails solution with a 'client server' based on react/redux client.
Ou aims was to create easily an app with drag and drop feature, sortable liste, ....

For each view , we develop a controller on ruby on rails that send data as json ( like api/v1/models...
In react, we wrote a route to get this data and rewrite a root for the user (like /models....)

For authentification we use a token, for pagination we manully write code, ....

Everything become more and more complex than the simple and standard MVC of Rails.

I know whats I have loose ( simplicity, clarity, speed) but I don't understand what I have win React.

Can you clarify what are the benefit of React ?

Comment: I could list a few but this question can only be answered based on opinion, so here's a link `https://dev.to/solutelabs/why-and-when-should-you-use-react-with-ruby-on-rails-2cfc#:~:text=It%C3%ADs%20easier%20and%20faster%20to,the%20APIs%20don%C3%ADt%20change%20much.`

Answer (score 1):

Well, React are made for reactive user interfaces. It means that if you want to make a dynamic complex views for your app, react will make things easier.

Because, with react you can make each element of your DOM to have a certain behavior and encapsulate it in a component. With plain js or jquery, you will have to make the markdown in html, add style in css and add that behaivor in js. And depend in css classes to encapsulate it.

So, if your app is less complex, like a simple CRUD or make redirections are not really affect the user experience, react is not required. But if you want to make a really complex interactive app, react will make things easier.

About redux, is a library to handle data. And, make react in charge of managing the interactions with the DOM while redux the interactions with the data. Also, i would recommend to make fetch with some async redux middleware like redux-saga to handle requests and really abstract all the data-related work from react.

I understand that if you follow the MVC structure would be a mess. More if you make components for each model. But if you really just make PagesContainers and handle routes with react-router or something similar, is not that complex. It depends on your architecture, more than the library itself. Like, if all your views has a layout, you don't have to make the same layout for each model, just handle it with react-router and only change the elements that change.